# RuntimeWarning: coroutine was never awaited in tests

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to test a async Python function using pytest. My test is passing with a warning, when it *should* be failing.

This is my test:

```
import asynctest
import pytest

from Foo.bar import posts

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_get_post_exists():
    returned_post = await posts.get_post('0')

    assert returned_post.id == 0
    assert returned_post.text == 'Text for the post body.'
    assert True == False
```

It passes with the following message:

```
================================== test session starts ===================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.4.2, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /path/path/path/path, inifile:
collected 1 item

tests/unit/route_logic/test_post_helpers.py .                                      [100%]

==================================== warnings summary ====================================
tests/unit/route_logic/test_post_helpers.py::test_get_post_exists
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:155: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'test_get_post_exists' was never awaited
    testfunction(**testargs)

-- Docs: http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
========================== 1 passed, 1 warnings in 0.10 seconds ==========================
```

Comment: Did you install `pytest-asyncio`? What does `pip list --format=freeze | grep asyncio` return when you run it in terminal?

Comment: Thing is, `coroutine 'my_coro' was never awaited` means that the coroutine object was never put into the event loop, so I suppose you are either missing `pytest-asyncio` that puts tests into event loop, or you have some custom hookimpls in your `conftest.py` that mess up with the event loop - if this is the case, you have to share your `conftest.py` code.

Comment: I needed to install `pytest-asyncio`, thank you.

Comment: @Jones to install or and also to import?

Comment: @may I don't remember, sorry.

Answer (score 9):

Here is the working demo using `pytest` and `pytest-asyncio`:

`Foo/bar/posts.py`:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

Post = namedtuple('Post', 'id text')


async def get_post(id: str):
    return Post(id=int(id), text='Text for the post body.')
```

`test_post_helpers.py`:

```py
import pytest

from Foo.bar import posts


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_get_post_exists():
    returned_post = await posts.get_post('0')
    assert returned_post.id == 0
    assert returned_post.text == 'Text for the post body.'
    assert True == False
```

Unit test result:

```sh
========================================================================================================================================================================= test session starts ==========================================================================================================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.5, pytest-5.3.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/python-codelab
plugins: asyncio-0.10.0
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

src/stackoverflow/49350821/test_post_helpers.py F                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                [100%]

=============================================================================================================================================================================== FAILURES ===============================================================================================================================================================================
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ test_get_post_exists _________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_get_post_exists():
        returned_post = await posts.get_post('0')
        assert returned_post.id == 0
        assert returned_post.text == 'Text for the post body.'
>       assert True == False
E       assert True == False

src/stackoverflow/49350821/test_post_helpers.py:11: AssertionError
========================================================================================================================================================================== 1 failed in 0.15s ===========================================================================================================================================================================
```

`assert True == False` cause the assertion fails as you wish.

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/python-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/49350821

Answer (score 5):

**You have to install [pytest-asyncio](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-asyncio/).**

```
pip install pytest-asyncio
```

You don't have to import it anywhere. Just decorate the async def tests with `@pytest.mark.asyncio`.

It was mentioned by in the @hoefling comments, I'm posting this answer just to make it more visible:

> `coroutine 'my_coro' was never awaited` means that the coroutine object was never put into the event loop, so I suppose you are either missing pytest-asyncio that puts tests into event loop.

Without pytest-asyncio, pytest doesn't know that it should `await` the async test. It just runs it as a non-async function, which is not enough to actually execute the async function body:

```
$ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12)
>>> async def foo():
...   raise Excepion('this is never raised')
...
>>> foo()
<coroutine object foo at 0x7f7d857d4cc8>
>>> exit()
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'foo' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```