# How to fix "RuntimeWarning: coroutine ... was never awaited" error on an async test that is part of a unittest.TestCase?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have a problem with running an asynchronous test.

My example:

```
import unittest
import asyncio
from asyncio import coroutine
import pytest
import os


class TestEcommerce(unittest.TestCase):

    async def assertFloatAlmostEqual(self, first, second, places=2, msg=""):
        """
        Used to compare float type values with the specified precision.
        Since with each test we can get numbers with slightly different accuracy - however, this is not an error
        :param msg:
        :param first:
        :param second:
        :param places:
        :return:
        """
        self.assertAlmostEqual(first, second, places=places, msg=msg)

    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_deep_analysis_find_complex(self):
        # Just for an example
        await self.assertFloatAlmostEqual(100.44, 100.445)
        pass
```

I get this error:

> kernel/test/test_demo.py::TestEcommerce::test_deep_analysis_find_complex
> /usr/lib/python3.10/unittest/case.py:549: RuntimeWarning: coroutine
> 'TestEcommerce.test_deep_analysis_find_complex' was never awaited
> method()   Enable tracemalloc to get traceback where the object was allocated.   See
> https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html#resource-warnings
> for more info.
>
> -- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html

I checked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49350821/runtimewarning-coroutine-was-never-awaited-in-tests) earlier, however, the answers in it did not work for me.

I also tried to remove `async` from the main function but then I get another error (which is actually expected)

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
def test_deep_analysis_find_complex(self):
    # Just for an example
    await self.assertFloatAlmostEqual(100.44, 100.445)
    pass
```

> E       await self.assertFloatAlmostEqual(100.44, 100.445) E
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> E       SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function

Can you tell me how to run this test?

Here is my environment info:

```
pip list --format=freeze | grep pytest
```

> pytest==7.4.0
> pytest-asyncio==0.21.1

```
python -V
```

> Python 3.10.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `pytest-asyncio` [docs](https://pytest-asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

> Note that test classes subclassing the standard unittest library are not supported. Users are advised to use unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase or an async framework such as asynctest.

You need to use `unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase` or something like `asynctest`, not `unittest.TestCase`.